# Android TV autostart script

Tags: boot, scripts, auto-start

I want to run a script after booting from a Android **TV** box (Xiaomi Mi Box)
I tried a lot but nothing works. Is there any option to 'activate' an `init.d` folder?

Comment: Just a side note, some app services (e.g., [Roku's](https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/dev-tools/tools-overview.md)) offer their own automation tools as part of their SDK's.  Not systemic, but might be useful in specific scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) to accomplish this.

There are several candidates for this e.g [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en) (free up to 5 macros) , [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) (free 7 day trial) etc *(but I am an intermediate user of the the latter hence prefer it)*

**Profile (or Trigger)**

Create a Profile which allows triggering of the Task after boot:

- Go to Profiles Tab and click the "+"
- Event ➡  System ➡  Device Boot
- Tap back to exit from this window

**Task**

You will notice as soon exit, you will be prompted to link this to a Task

- Scroll all the way up the Task list select "New Task + "
- You can name this Task anything (optional).
- Click "+" to add new Action
- Code ➡ Run Shell [ Command (`enter script command`) , Tick "Use Root" if it needs root]
- Tap back to exit from this task

*Explanation: Soon after boot, your predefined script will be executed by Tasker*